# python-gnupg: retrieve public key of a signed message

Tags: python, pgp, public-key, gnupg

I would like to know the public key of the user that generates an encrypted/signed PGP message.

I looked at the python-gnupg API but I just found how to check that the signature is OK

```
GPG().verify(data)
```

If the signature can be verified, it means that the public key is in the keyring.  How can I found which one it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a look at the `fingerprint` attribute of the `gnupg.Verify` object returned by the `verify` method.  For example:

```
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG()
>>> v = gpg.verify(data)
>>> v.fingerprint
u'3D2822FCA7D73D07F65B1514C9A99684DEDF97D5'
```

You can then filter `list_keys` to find the key in question:

```
>>> [k for k in gpg.list_keys(v.fingerprint)
     if k['fingerprint'] == v.fingerprint]
```

Answer (score 2):

PGP doesn't store public keys inside of signed/encrypted messages, it stores key identifier (8-byte part of the hash of the public-key fields).
So you should look for something called 'key id' in the documentation.
Here it is:

When a signature is verified, signer information is held in attributes of verified: username, key_id, signature_id, fingerprint, trust_level and trust_text.

Comment: Actually it stores more than 8 bytes of the keyID, but how much you see is determined by gpg.conf settings.

Comment: Actually  it stored exactly 8 bytes of key fingerprint in the encrypted message (see RFC 4880, 5.1). Or do we talk about the different things?

Comment: We're talking about related things.  You're right about the 8 octets for tag 1 packet types.  However, there is enough information in the packet to identify at least the long form of the key, if not the entire fingerprint.  If you run gpg --list-packets or pgpdump on an encrypted file you should see what I mean.